# Padding lists for accurate plotting

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following data which is in the form of irregular/non rectangular arrays

```
list1 = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {11}, {12}}
```

To transpose it for plotting, I have to use (because of the irregular shape)

```
list2 = Flatten[list1, {{2}, {1}}]
```

This is now a $3\times1$ column. 
I want to plot this data, So I use the `ListLinePlot` as

```
ListLinePlot[list2, DataRange -> {1, 3}, Frame -> True]
```

The three rows are plotted as three curves, but the problem is that the upper two curves which correspond to the second and third row of `list2` also start from `1` on the x-axis.? Shouldn't they start from 2 instead of 1? I thought I could use `PadLeft` or `PadRight` with empty entries `{}` to the left or right of the last two (2 element) rows of `list2` (to make them 6 element rows, like the first row of `list2`) to force the two curves to start from 2, but I failed. Could someone tell any workaround?

Comment: Does `ListLinePlot[Transpose[PadRight[list1]], DataRange -> {1, 3}]` do what you want?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Thanks. But it gives zeros on right and left which actually do not do the trick, however, if they are somehow empty, would do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[PadRight[list1, Automatic, Null]], 
 DataRange -> {1, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly..